# How to connect React app with DB created with Laravel - I tried using proxy but received error 405

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I am looking for a solution on how to connect my Laravel API data to my react app so I could use methods like get,post, delete. What I did to be able to reach my DB with my React app is: 
1. I enabled cors in Laravel,
2. I also tried to install proxy in my React App and created setupProxy.js file. That is to say, followed proxy usage guidelines.

However, when I want to use POST method to add new data to my DB I get this error from react server: 
'POST http://localhost:3000/categories 405 (Method Not Allowed)'
and "createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 405 at createError (createError.js:16) at settle (settle.js:17)at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:59)"

My App.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './components/layout/Header';
import Categories from './components/data/Categories';
import './App.scss';
import './App2.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import AddCategory from './components/layout/AddCategory';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    categories: []
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('/categories').then((response) => this.setState({ categories: response.data.data }));
  }
  addCategory = (name) => {
    axios.post('/categories', {
      name: name,
      // image: image
    },
    {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}).then(response => this.setState({ categories: [...this.state.categories, response.data.data]}))
   }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Header />
          <Route exact path="/" render={props => (
            <React.Fragment>
              <AddCategory addCategory= { this.addCategory}/>
              <Categories categories={this.state.categories} />
            </React.Fragment>
          )} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

AddCategory.js file:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';


export class AddCategory extends Component {
    state = {
        name: '',
        // image: '',
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.addCategory(this.state.name);
        // this.setState({ name: '' });
    }


    onChange = (e) => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value})

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               <h1>Add a New Category</h1>
               <form action='/' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} type='post'>
                   <input type="text" name="name" value={ this.state.name } onChange= { this.onChange } />
                   <input type="submit" value="Add" />
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default AddCategory
```

I would really appreciate the help with this.
This is the first time I am trying to connect front-end with my back-end environment. Maybe there is another way besides proxy to do that. However I am looking for the solutions which would allow to connect to multiple APIS.

Thank you!